# Using awk to find numbers in KB then change and replace to GB and display the whole line

Tags: awk

Trying to search/below numbers in below in KB unit (Cover KB: 7606353,) so it will be displayed as (Cover GB: 7.25,) I have tried many awk options to change below numbers from KB unit to GB  and other complicated tools that I use to send outputs to files then to use again, my target is to have like a single awk so it find the number after (Cover KB: ) and divide it by /1024/1024 and change KB to GB .. the maximum effort i reached was

```
awk '($NF == ($NF+0)){printf("%s %6.2f\n",$0,$10/1024/1024)}END{print ""}'
```

but that will display the number i need at the end of the line while i needed to replace it..Tried -F to cut some columns and didn't get the needed output as well.

Source:

```
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover KB: 7606353, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover KB: 7268433, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover KB: 6895144, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover KB: 6506311, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover KB: 5590773, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover KB: 5192929, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover KB: 4645949, TARGET GB: 1048576
```

Change to:

```
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover GB: 7.25, TARGET GB: 1048576   
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover GB: 6.93, TARGET GB: 1048576   
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover GB: 6.58, TARGET GB: 1048576   
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover GB: 6.20, TARGET GB: 1048576   
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover GB: 5.33, TARGET GB: 1048576   
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover GB: 4.95, TARGET GB: 1048576   
XX YY ZZ checknpr  Y  checkagain  DEV  Cover GB: 4.43, TARGET GB: 1048576
```

Comment: SO isn't a free code writing service; you're expected to show your research and coding efforts; please update the question with some of the `awk` code you've tried along with the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: can some input lines *not* have the entry `Cover KB:`? are all lines formatted exactly as displayed in the sample input (eg, `Cover KB: ######,` always shows up as the white-space delimited fields #8-10)?

Comment: What's your field separator? Multiple spaces or tabs?

Comment: unfortunately sometimes spaces sometimes tabs but fortunately they are the same columns and alignment

Comment: Yes they are always the same syntax like above but as mentioned the separation could be space / 2 space / tab

Comment: This question comes up a lot - have you searched the archives?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
awk '{$9=$12; $10=sprintf("%.2f,", $10/$13)} {print}' file
```

Output:

```
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 7.25, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 6.93, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 6.58, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 6.20, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 5.33, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 4.95, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 4.43, TARGET GB: 1048576
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed much appreciated Cyrus @cyrus

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` works without knowing the field number of the condition

```
$ awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/^KB:/){ $i="GB:";
    $(i+1)=sprintf("%.2f,",$(i+1)/1024^2) } } }1' file
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 7.25, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 6.93, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 6.58, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 6.20, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 5.33, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 4.95, TARGET GB: 1048576
XX YY ZZ checknpr Y checkagain DEV Cover GB: 4.43, TARGET GB: 1048576
```

Comment: this is even better Andre :):):) will try to edit to fit some other files I hope I don't ask again

Comment: @mshafey No worries. Glad it works for you. Just keep in mind that you have to adjust the condition matching if you have other `KB:`s in your lines.